# Can't set just 1 date field in Laravel with carbon, all of them get changed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have some extra dates in a particular model in Laravel 5.2: `'deleted_at', 'due_at', 'reminded_at', 'paid_at'`, as well as the timestamps `'created_at', 'updated_at'`. All of these are `null`able as well.

**TLDR Edit: It basically seems that a few extra fields are being used as additional updated_at fields when I do `$object->save()`**

All objects have `'created_at', 'updated_at', 'due_at'` set, and when I'm trying to set `'paid_at'` to `now` it's changing not only paid_at, but all the non-`null` fields to `now` (edit: apart from created_at)

```
public function postPaid($id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($id);

    $invoice->paid_at = Carbon::now();

    $invoice->save();

    return back();   
}
```

Results for a row before I run this:

```
| due_at   | reminded_at | paid_at | created_at          | updated_at    | deleted_at |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2016-02-10 07:29:41 |NULL | NULL | 2016-01-23 16:31:22 | 2016-01-23 16:31:22 | NULL |
```

Results for a row after I run it:

```
| due_at   | reminded_at | paid_at | created_at          | updated_at    | deleted_at |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2016-01-23 22:19:00 | NULL | 2016-01-23 22:19:00 | 2016-01-23 16:31:22 | 2016-01-23 22:19:00 | NULL |
```

So it's setting paid_at, but all other dates are also changed to `Carbon::now()` apart from created_at

Comment: it is quite unclear have you tried to var_dump $invoice->paid_at ?

Comment: at which point? during the `postPaid()`?

Comment: yes inside the postPaid() after retrieving the invoice

Comment: check the defaults that the migrations set on your fields, perhaps do to the change in mysql 5.7

Comment: @яша paid_at is `null` before I set it, shows as a carbon object for `now`s date after I set it. Another field (due_at) is the correct date before I set paid_at, correct date after I set it, and then `now`s date once I `save()` the object.

As in my edit to my OP, it seems like these other date fields are being updated with the `updated_at` field when I save

Comment: @lagbox ah yes, that was it.. I haven't set any defaults in my migrations, but due_at isn't nullable like the other fields, which made it set defaut to `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for some reason. Nice catch!

Comment: Could you throw the answer up for others to find?